# how to correctly use search query of Facebook graph API (android)?

Tags: java, facebook

I'm trying to run a query to search for locations using search query facebok graf api for android.

If I try to run this query in the Graph API Explorer, I get [this result](http://2.firepic.org/2/images/2015-10/16/zl5zqymxegxa.png).

But programmatically it is impossible. I try to make so:

```
new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),"/search?q=coffee&type=place&center=37.76,-122.427",null,HttpMethod.GET,new GraphRequest.Callback()
    {
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response)
        {
            Log.v("HelloFacebook", response.toString());
        }
    }).executeAsync();
}
```

i get nothing (param distance must be number)

if I try without distance i get too nothing, but another message (An access token is required to request this resourse and too)

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right syntax for search in Facebook graph API:

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(
  accessToken,
  "/search",
  new GraphRequest.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
      // Insert your code here
    }
});

Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("type", "place");
parameters.putString("center", "53,27");
parameters.putString("distance", "30000");
request.setParameters(parameters);
request.executeAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax that Vadim Korzun provided did unfortunately not directly work for me. But it gave me some ideas. I wanted to search for people by names. Here the code I impelemted according to the `newPlacesSearchRequest(...)`-method of the official `GraphRequest`-class:

```
    AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();

    Bundle parameters = new Bundle(2);
    parameters.putString("type", "user");
    parameters.putString("q", "Albert Einstein");

    GraphRequest.Callback wrapper = new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            try {
                JSONObject  jso = response.getJSONObject();
                JSONArray   arr = jso.getJSONArray( "data" );

                for (int i = 0; i < (arr.length()); i++) {
                    JSONObject json_obj = arr.getJSONObject(i);

                    // START: Your code goes here
                    String id = json_obj.getString("id");
                    String name = json_obj.getString("name");
                    // ...
                    // END: Your code goes here
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("name: ", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    };

    GraphRequest gr = new GraphRequest(accessToken, "search", parameters, HttpMethod.GET, wrapper);
    gr.executeAsync();
```

hope this helps...